# Converting perl regex to Java

Tags: java, regex, perl

I have a piece of regex I've been using in Perl to parse a large text file containing every stored procedure in an Oracle database. It looks like this:

```
/create\s+(proc(edure)?|function)\s+\[*(dbo)?\]*\.*\[*(\w+)/i
```

I'm not too familiar with Perl though, so would ideally like to convert this to Java. I've tried running it through some converters, which produces:

```
"/create\\s+(proc(edure)?|function)\\s+\\[*(dbo)?\\]*\\.*\\[*(\\w+)/i"
```

However, this doesn't seem to match any correct input. Can anyone give me some pointers in converting this correctly to Java?

**Sample Data:**

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON 
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE AddNewTc                       

@TCN NVARCHAR(100),                
@TCM NTEXT,                
@TCOLE IMAGE = NULL,                
@BYSPID INT = 0,
```

Only the "CREATE PROCEDURE" line should be matched.

Comment: can you please add expected input/output to help us translating this regex? i don't know Perl ReGex syntax so this can be helpful

Comment: have you double-slash those slash? java string slash need escaping

Comment: @J-16SDiZ: I did, but behind the scenes SO is playing with how both regex are represented. I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: @AndrewMartin, use 4 spaces instead of > to get proper display of the double \'s

Answer (score 1):

The converter works just fine, but you will need to change a couple of things.

```
/create\\s+(proc(edure)?|function)\\s+\\[*(dbo)?\\]*\\.*\\[*(\\w+)/i
```

1. Java does not have inline-regexes like you do in perl & javascript. You will need to use the [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) & [Matcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) API for regex support.
2. Due to the lack of inline-regex, pattern modifiers are done separately with [flags](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#field_summary).

Applying step 1 (remove prepended `/` and appended `/`) and step 2 (replace `/i` with `Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE`) you would get something like:

```java
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile("create\\s+(proc(edure)?|function)\\s+\\[*(dbo)?\\]*\\.*\\[*(\\w+)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
 boolean matches = p.matcher(str).matches();
```

Comment: `find()` is more appropriate here.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this one:

```
"create\\s+((procedure)?|(function))?\\s+\\([(dbo)?\\]\\.\\[)?(\\w+)"
```

It should work, but you need to add upper case if you need to match some, or add a "i" flag to your regex to ignore case.

in Java, ecape character \ must be escaped with another \ to escape in regex syntax (too much escape !)

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/jD8vA5/1)

Comment: I think you're having the issue I was having. Adding the extra slashs on SO doesn't show.

Comment: Oh, in fact i typed them, but need to add a code area to show them, gonna fix it now

Answer (score 0):

The [JRegex project](http://jregex.sourceforge.net/) (which I am neither affiliated with nor have been a user of) might interest you. It claims to provide a Java library to handle perl regular expressions.